NoClassDefFoundError when running JDA on Minecraft Java Plugin
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        BotStart.botStart();
    }
}

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.GatewayIntent;
import java.util.EnumSet;

public class BotStart {
    public static void botStart() {
        String token = "(Bot Token)";
        JDABuilder.createLight(token, EnumSet.of(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES, GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT))
                .addEventListeners(new BotListener())
                .build();
    }
}

plugins {
    id("java")
}

group = "org.xeon.bot"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/")
    maven("https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots")
    maven("https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/central")
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.10.0"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
    compileOnly("org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.21-R0.1-SNAPSHOT")
    compileOnly("net.dv8tion:JDA:5.0.1")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

Built to jar file using Gradle, and the error in Minecraft server log:
[21:50:55 INFO]: [MinecraftDiscordBot] Enabling MinecraftDiscordBot v0.1*
[21:50:55 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling MinecraftDiscordBot v0.1 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/GatewayIntent
        at DiscordMinecraftBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/org.xeon.bot.Main.onEnable(Main.java:8) ~[DiscordMinecraftBot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:288) ~[paper-api-1.21-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at .....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.GatewayIntent
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.loadClass0(PluginClassLoader.java:197) ~[paper-api-1.21-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        ... 19 more
[21:50:55 INFO]: [MinecraftDiscordBot] Disabling MinecraftDiscordBot v0.1

It appears NoClassDefFoundError when running JDA on Minecraft Java Plugin.
I saw the reason of this problem is in dependencies, but I cannot find how to solve.
Can't use English well. Sorry for you in advance.

You are including the dependency for JDA as compileOnly but it is needed for execution. That's the reason it is missing and so triggers a ClassNotFoundException. Change the dependency to implementation as the documentation of JDA recommends.
    implementation("net.dv8tion:JDA:$version") // replace $version with the latest version


Thank you, but it didn't help me. I changed compileOnly to implementation and reloaded gradle, made .jar file again, but same error occurs.
